# AJAX GET REQUESTS

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Please help, I'm stuck here. I have a problem with passing input parameter to my C# controller. I tried really a lot of things I found here, but still there's some mistake.

Here is code:

```
  var a = $.ajax({        
    type:"GET",
    url: "/Weather1/Weather_get",
    data: "location=Paris%",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false, 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, //succes
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }//error
}) //ajax;
```

And here is controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Weather_get(String  location) etc etc...
```

Everything I tried gives me input location NULL. I know my controller is working fine because I get data from it, but I really need that data to be for specific location, so that's why I need it like this. Also don't want to change it to POST because this is homework problem so I have to have both HttpPost and HttpGet in my controller.

Comment: Why is there a `%` in the value?  Try URL encoding that with `encodeURIComponent()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Thanks, this was causing problem for me!

Comment: Are you using MVC or WebAPI? I guess it's the latter because of the naming convention, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var place="Paris%";
 var a = $.ajax({        
    type:"GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("Weather_get","Weather1")',
    data: '{ "location":"' + place+ '"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false, 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, //succes
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }//error
}) //ajax;
```

Comment: It could be easier to simply remove the `contentType` header.

Comment: When I try it like this, controller is not found at all.

Answer (score 1):

just include the parameter name in your controller and the value you want to pass like this.

```
$.ajax({        
        type:"GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("Weather_get","Weather1")',
        data: { location:paris},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false, 
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, //succes
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }//error
    }) //ajax;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way ASP.Net binds the HTTP request URL to the model used by your controller is controlled in part by the routing engine.

If you navigate to

```
/Weather1/Weather_get/Paris
```

do you see the data from Paris?

If so, you could modify your AJAX this way
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "/Weather1/Weather_get/Paris"
        (etc.)
    })

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use JSON.stringify.

something like this:

```
var data = {
   location: "Paris%"
};

var a = $.ajax({        
    type:"GET",
    url: "/Weather1/Weather_get",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: false, 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, //succes
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }//error
}) //ajax;
```